# SCSS extend a nested selector and override the nested rulesets

Tags: css, sass

Ok so I have a placeholder with a nested selector:

```
%block {
  .title {
    font-size:12px;
  }
}
```

I want to extend it and ADD to the `.title` class:

```
.superblock {
  @extend %block;
  .title {
    font-weight:bold;
  }
}
```

The answer I WANT is this:

```
.superblock .title {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold; }
```

However, the answer I get is this:

```
.superblock .title {
  font-size: 12px; }

.superblock .title {
  font-weight: bold; }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just how it works? To clarify I want to merge it. If I add something directly inside the `.superblock` and add like another `.superblock2` which also extends %block they merge without any problems.

Comment: This appears to be just the way it works.. Take a look at the nesting reference.. http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_rules

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Sass has no functionality for "merging" duplicate selectors.  You'll need to find another utility to do this after the CSS has been compiled.

The `@extend` directive isn't just a way to use classes in place of mixins (similar to LESS style mixin calls).  Why `@extend` works the way it does becomes clear when you're extending normal classes instead of extend classes:

```
.block {
  font-size:12px;
}

.foo {
    @extend .block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Output:

```
.block, .foo {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.foo {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Using an extend class just suppresses the emission of the original class name.

Now that you've seen why `@extend` works the way it does, *do you still want what `@extend` offers?*  If the answer is no, then you need to use a mixin:

```
@mixin block {
    // styles
    .title {
        font-size: 12px;
        @content;
    }
}

.superblock {
    @include block {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.superblock .title {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is turing out to be a deal breaker for our project. Do you know of another css preprocessor or a post-scss utility that does the merging?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much it. SASS produces extended declarations separately.

And it has no functionality of grouping declarations by selector, it's not that smart.

But you need not worry that much about CSS cleanness. Modern web servers serve CSS gzipped, all duplication will be nicely compressed.

Comment: True, it is just the automated performance enhancher in me that was restless. Thank you

Comment: @run_the_race, I think you're wrong. OP's "want" and "get" code snippets are functionally equivalent.

Comment: you are right, I deleted my non-value adding comment.

Answer (score 0):

LESS can do that. However you would write:

```
.superblock {
  .title {
    .block .title;
  }
}
```

Not sure if it works with @extend too.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a tools, I used it to clean the css
https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss

"A grunt task for removing unused CSS from your projects with UnCSS."

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to remove unused rules, they're asking how to override rules included in a SCSS @extend().