# Use all properties of Bootstrap's input error CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-sass

I'd like my input to appear the same as Bootstrap's styling for errors. What should this class extend from bootstrap to do this? Including the styling for :focus which is red glow rather than the default blue glow.

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched.ng-dirty:not(form) {
    // extend bootstrap style?
}
```

I've used `.has-error`, this will only work if there is an element further up the tree with the class .has-error which doesn't make sense to me. So this works:

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched.ng-dirty:not(form) {
    @extend .has-error;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    ..
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required> 
</div>
```

How can I get it to work by having just .has-error applied to the input without putting on the upper level element.

Comment: what version of bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap-sass 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't. This class appears not only for input, but for labels too. That's why `.has-error` using with `.form-group`.

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086377/scss-extend-a-nested-selector-and-override-the-nested-rulesets) as yours.

You can just create new class and add styles straight to your input:

```
.some-class:focus {
    border-color: #843534;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
}
.some-class {
    border-color: #a94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```